# Setting up a shared folder in Linux

Tags: linux, user-accounts, file-permissions

I'm trying to set up a folder in my home directory that will be shared with another user, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've done: I have tried two different ways using ACL's and `chown`/`chgrp`, etc.

I set up a group called `sharedgroup` and added both my user (`john`) and `fred` to it:

```
$ groups john
john wheel sharedgroup
$ groups fred
sharedgroup fred 
$ mkdir /home/john/shared
$ vim /home/john/shared/hello.txt #typed in some text, saved it
$ chown -R :sharedgroup shared
$ chmod -R o=-rwx shared
$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 2 john sharedgroup 4096 Sep 9 21:14 shared
$ ls -l shared
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john sharedgroup 7 Sep 9 21:14 hello.txt
```

(Note: I also tried adding the `s` permission, but that didn't help.)

Then when I log out of the server and log back in as `fred` and try these commands they fail:

```
$ vim /home/john/shared/hello.txt #won't allow me to write; opens a blank file
$ cd /home/john/shared
-bash: cd: /home/john/cis: Permission Denied
$ ls /home/john/shared
-ls: /home/john/shared: Permission Denied
$ ls -lad /home/john/shared
-ls: /home/john/shared: Permission Denied
$ id fred
uid=500(fred) gid=502(sharedgroup) groups=502(sharedgroup),500(fred) 
context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the output of `id` and `ls -lad /home/john/shared` when logged in as fred?  That `PERMISSION DENIED` error does not look like a linux error message - is it cut and paste?

Comment: ok posted and changed to actual output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does fred have access to `/home/john` ?

Without access to the parent, you can't access the subdirectory.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory

Comment: interesting I ran chown -R :sharedgroup /home/john then tried again but it still gave me permission denied with fred? is that what you mean by giving him permission

Comment: Ah hah! I had to also run chmod g=rwx /home/john then it worked Thanks!

Comment: for clarification purposes to fix the problem I ran chown -R :sharedgroup /home/john; chmod g=rwx /home/john

Comment: fred (or sharedgroup, or everybody) will need execute permission on `/home` and `/home/john`.